# Clojure - how to make def forms evaluate at run time instead of compile time

Tags: clojure

The core problem I'm trying to solve is: have a `settings` object that is loaded from a `settings.json file`, every time when the program is started.

I initially used code like

`(def settings (load-settings "settings.json"))`

but during deploy I was surprised to discover that the init form is being evaluated at compile time rather than run time - the compilation  was failing because there was no `settings.json` file in place.

So the Y part of the problem is - can I delay the evaluation of the init form without employing refs or otherwise complicating the usage of the object? Or am I missing some core concept here?

Comment: Are you AOT-compiling the namespace? Is that when the exception is happening?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Answering my own question because I happened to find the exact thing I wanted thanks to @Alex.

So, quoting [this thread from the Clojure mailing list from 2008](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/clojure/hhih2Ty7-Lc/yXa43-X441gJ),

> While  compiling, a *compile-files* flag is set. [...] If your file
>   has some def  initializers you don't want to run at compile-time, you
>   can  conditionalize them like this:
>
> `(def foo (when-not *compile-files* (my-runtime-init)))`
>
> in which case foo will be nil at compile time.

I tested the behavior with the following code:

```
(def evaluated-at-runtime
  (when-not *compile-files*
    (println "i am evaluated")
    "value"))

(defn -main [& args]
  (println evaluated-at-runtime))


>lein uberjar
... "(i am evaluated)" is not printed)

>java -jar test-app.jar
i am evaluated
value
```

There's a caveat here that the init form will be evaluated *as soon as the program is launched*, before the `-main` method, this may not be flexible enough for everyone, but then I direct you to one of the other great responses to this question.

Answer (score 10):

One possible solution is to load your settings file lazily, i.e. the first time it's actually used. You can do it with [`delay` macro](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/delay):

```
(def settings
  (delay (load-settings "settings.json")))
```

The only difference is that you'll have to [deref](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/deref) your `settings` object every time you'll want to use it:

```
(println @settings)
```

Answer (score 1):

*future* and *delay* could both be used.

[future](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/future) runs in the background and avoid waiting for the evaluation to be finished.

[delay](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/delay) would not do anything you try to access the value.

```
(def string-sample "(do (Thread/sleep 5000)  (println \"done\") 1)")

; execute immediately
(def settings (load-string string-sample))
(println settings)

; execute in the background, returns immediately
(def settings (future (load-string string-sample )))
(println @settings)

; evaluated when calling it
(def settings (delay (load-string string-sample)))
(println @settings)
```

Answer (score 1):

What not just use defn instead of def.

```
(defn settings [] (load-settings "settings.json"))
```

Then use `(settings)` instead of `settings`.

Comment: Because in many use cases you are referring to `settings` many times, sometimes hundreds of times per second, and you don't want to read and parse a file every time you need to access a setting.

Comment: You can easily memoize it if you want to cache. Or you can cache a value in a def form. Or you can add a parameter to allow the function consumer to choose cached or fresh copy of data.